# accessing the highest value in hash of an hash in perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, loops, printing, hash-of-hashes

so i have a hash of an hash that looks something like this:

```
my %hash = (
    'fruits' => {
        'apple'    => 34,
        'orange'   => 30,
        'pear'     => 45,
    },
    'chocolates' => {
        'snickers' => 35,
        'lindt'    => 20,
        'mars'     => 15,
    },
);
```

I want to access only the fruit which is max in number and chocolate which is max in number. the output should look like:

fruits: pear 
chocolates : snickers

```
foreach my $item (keys %hash){
#print "$item:\t"; # this is the object name
foreach my $iteminitem (keys %{$hash{$item}})
    {
    my $longestvalue = (sort {$a<=>$b} values %{$hash{$item}})[-1]; #this stores the longest value
     print "the chocolate/fruit corresponding to the longestvalue" ;   

     #iteminitem will be chocolate/fruit name
    }
 print "\n";
}
```

I know it is not difficult but I am blanking out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sorts the keys of each hashref by descending value, so the max is the first element returned:

```
my %hash = (
    chocolates => { lindt => 20, mars => 15, snickers => 35 },
    fruits     => { apple => 34, orange => 30, pear => 45 },
);

while (my ($key, $hashref) = each %hash) {
    my ($max) = sort {$hashref->{$b} <=> $hashref->{$a}} keys %$hashref;
    print "$key: $max\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
fruits: pear
chocolates: snickers
```

Comment: And there were no syntax errors because the data structure is generated by previous lines of code and I typed it here! but thanks again :)

Comment: Note: whenever I want to share a data structure, I use [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) to print it out.  `dd \%hash;`.  One can also use [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), but I prefer the format of the former.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max);

my %hash = (
    'fruits' => {
        'apple'    => 34,
        'orange'   => 30,
        'pear'     => 45,
    },
    "chocolates" => {
        'snickers' => 35,
        'lindt'    => 20,
        'mars'     => 15,
    },
);

for (keys %hash) {
    my $max = max values %{$hash{$_}};  # Find the max value 
    my %rev = reverse %{$hash{$_}};     # Reverse the internal hash
    print "$_: $rev{$max}\n";           # Print first key and lookup by max value
}
```

**Output:**

```
fruits: pear
chocolates: snickers
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you likely want `List::UtilsBy`:

```
use List::UtilsBy 'max_by';

my %hash = (
    chocolates => { lindt => 20, mars => 15, snickers => 35 },
    fruits     => { apple => 34, orange => 30, pear => 45 },
);

foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    my $subhash = $hash{$key};
    my $maximal = max_by { $subhash->{$_} } keys %$subhash;
    print "$key: $maximal\n";
}
```

For this small example it probably doesn't matter too much, but for much larger cases, there's a big difference. This will run in `O(n)` time for the size of the hash, whereas the "sort and take first index" solution will take `O(n log n)` time, much slower, to sort the list of keys, only to then throw away all but the first result.